# Use date in the URL of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

So I've created a custom post type, say `reviews`, and its archive is available at `<domain>/reviews/`. I want to categorize them by date. So every day (or week) I publish a `reviews` type post and I want its url to be `<domain>/reviews/2013/09/05/<post-name>`, so that users will be able to list all the `reviews` from specific year, month or day. Just like we have a similar feature for the regular posts. All the plugins I've tried are old and aren't working with WP 3.6. So is there any solution (maybe even built-in)? Or at least some direction so I can code it myself? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom post types can not use the "day/name" permalink structure defined in WordPress permalinks settings.  You need to add your own rewrite rules to fit your needs.

For example:

```
add_action('init','my_rewrite_rules');
function my_rewrite_rules(){
    // Replace custom_post_type_slug with the slug of your custom post type
    add_rewrite_rule( 'custom_post_type_slug/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(.+)/?$', 'index.php?custom_post_type_slug='.$matches[4], 'top' );
}
```

Note that I've not tested the code above.  You need to flush the rewrite rules before you test it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, however this rewrite rule redirects to the index page for some reason + as I understand, there's no option for archive for custom post types (just like we have for regular posts `<domain>/2013/09` etc.), which is the important part here. Am I right?

Comment: Are you really redirected to index page? I've tried a similar rewrite rule and I'm no redirected, I get the home page of my site but there is no redirection, so I think the rewrite rules are not the corrects but I still think that this can be done adding the correct rewrite rules.

Comment: Yes, instead of the article itself, I get an index page (which is a progress in some sense, because previously I simply got 404).

Comment: I have no time today to investigate this. You can check [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) and see how it does the job.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works fine now. How could have I missed this plugin!